# Preloading the Jupyter Notebook with specific classes/functions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to preload a notebook with specific classes/functions that I've defined in another file. More specifically, I'd like to do this with python (something like loading a profile, containing all relevant classes/functions). Currently, I'm generating notebooks with python and starting them automatically on the server. Because different "profiles" need these notebooks, they need different classes and functions without specifically importing them.

When generating a jupyter notebook, I simply copy a jupyter notebook "template" to a specific file and let the user open this automatically.
Can I set some sort of profile in

```
"metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3",
   "profile": "lab_5" // <-- 
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.13"
  }
 },
```

where "lab_5" would preload the necessary classes?

Comment: You generate jupyter notebook files programmatically using some sort of template. Why don't you edit the template (programmatically) to include some script or magic command or special instruction and let the users execute or follow?

Comment: @swatchai Preferably, I'd like to start the notebook completely clean. Ideally, the notebook would be completely clean, having only one empty cell.

Comment: @swatchai Python has functions that are preloaded without importing anything. Think of the standard str methods. What I try to achieve is to define my own methods are have them preloaded without the need to import anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start Jupyter notebook (or lab), if you have python script file(s) in

```
location_of_ipython_profile/startup/
```

then they will run on every IPython startup (to serve as standard ipython kernel). For example, on my machine I have a file named `00-first.py` and it has simple content as follows:

```
import numpy as np
```

If there are other scripts, say, `50-middle.py` and `99-last.py`, they also run consecutively.

When I open a new Jupyter notebook with ipython kernel. I will have many thing pre-executed according to those script files. For the first script, `00-first.py`, it provides the symbol `np` to use right away. So, I can run `print(np.pi)` and get `3.141592...` as output.

To get the `location_of_ipython_profile`, one can run magic command on Jupyter notebook:

```
!ipython locate profile
```

In my case, I get `C:\Users\swatc\.ipython\profile_default`. To list all the files in the `startup` folder, I run:

```
!dir C:\Users\swatc\.ipython\profile_default\startup\*.*
```

Remember that there can be several python profiles on your computer. All the above is valid for the default profile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because your answer says "profile_default", is it possible to add more profiles and accordingly load those profiles based on certain parameters? E.g. can I load a profile called "profile_lab_5"?

Comment: The scripts will be in `C:\Users\swatc\.ipython\profile_lab_5\startup\`.

Comment: About creating and using `profile`: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html

Comment: Thank you @swatchai, I will report back as soon as I've tested it.