# How to run a "start-up" code when launching IPython (aka Jupyter) notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In every notebook I launch do data analysis, I need to import several libraries (e.g. matplotlib, numpy, etc)

Is there a way to have those imports automatically executed for every IPython kernel I launch? so I don't have to type them every time?

Comment: Find `.ipython/profile_default/setup` in your home directory. Any .py files you put in there will get executed when you start a new kernel.

Comment: @TBurgis how do I find this file in Windows?

Comment: It should be in `C:\Users\YourUserName`.

Comment: Read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325807/preloading-the-jupyter-notebook-with-specific-classes-functions/54341949#54341949

Comment: This approach works for the first time you launch the IPython notebook. It does not work when you restart the kernel