# Loading an IPython (--profile=SOMETHING) kernel in a notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've asked the following question, some time ago: [Preloading the Jupyter Notebook with specific classes/functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325807/preloading-the-jupyter-notebook-with-specific-classes-functions)

This works great when I start the interpreter with `ipython --profile=DOS` in my terminal. I have all the predefined functionalities available in the interpreter.

My question is, how do I load this into a jupyter notebook? So far, I can only load python2 or python 3.

Say a jupyter notebook configuration looks like

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "test\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "print(\"test\")"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.6.7"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Can I use a configuration where it uses `ipython3 --profile=DOS`, resulting in loading the predefined functionalities?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a customized `kernelspecs` folder under one of the `JUPYTER_PATH`s, as demonstrated in the [documentation](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/advanced/migrating.html#changing-ipython-s-profile-using-custom-kernelspecs).

> If you do want to change the IPython kernel’s profile, you can’t do this at the server command-line anymore. Kernel arguments must be changed by modifying the kernelspec. You can do this without relaunching the server. Kernelspec changes take effect every time you start a new kernel.

For example, add the `--profile=DOS` option to a custom kernelspec under `.../kernels/mycustomDOSpython/kernel.json`, where "mycustomDOSpython" is your new kernel's name, which will automatically appear on the "New" dropdown button of the jupyter notebook server.

```json
{
 "argv": ["python3", "-m", "ipykernel",
          "--profile=DOS",
          "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "Python 3 with profile DOS",
 "language": "python"
}
```

Then, in your `.ipynb` notebook file, change the "name" of the "kernelspec" correspondingly:

```json
"kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "mycustomDOSpython"
  },
```